# Calculate the sum S (z) of the power series for z on the convergence disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Calculate the sum S (z) of the power series for z on the convergence disk
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(z-i)^n$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\ln(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nz^n$, for $\mid z\mid\lt1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^(n+1)}{n}(z)^n$ I'm calculating derivative $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(z)^(n-1)$ Finally I have $\frac{1}{1+z}$ and later when I count the integral i have ln(1+z) what you have written

Comment: So I have $\ln(1+z-i)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n(z-i)^n$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  Note the extra minus sign.  So you get $-\ln(1+z-i)$.

Comment: Ok, I want to also calculate the radius of convergence R of the series. When I take series equal ln(1+z) I have R=1, because   $\sqrt[n]{(−1)^{n+1}}=1$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ but how is when i have $(z-i)^n$?

Comment: It's still $1$, but now centered at $i$.